# In Maximo, how do I get in between workflow process whether data in the table has been modified?

Tags: db2, workflow, maximo

I want to show a different option to the user in workflow through input node, depending upon whether the user has modified the record or not.

Problem is if I would use a condition node with custom class to detect whether object has been modified by some person or not in between the workflow process then as soon as the person clicks on route workflow the save is automatically called and isModified() flag gets false, How do I get in condition node whether some person has modified the record or not.

I have to show different options to the user if he has modified and different option on routing workflow if he have not modified.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to enable eAudit on the object and then to check whether eauditusername on the most recent audit record for that object bears the userid of the current user.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hokey and tempts fate, but if your condition node is early in the workflow's route when this button is pressed, you could try and check to see if the changedate on the object (assuming you are working with one of the many objects that has one) is within the last 5 seconds. There is a gap where the record could be routed twice within a few seconds, but the gap is fairly hard to hit. There is also a gap where if the system slows down at that point and takes more than 5 seconds to get to and run your condition, then it would appear to be not modified. You can play with the delay to find a sweet spot of the fewest false positives and negatives.